# Displaying data from a Json array using Retrofit in a textview

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit2

I'm trying to display data from a Json array using Retrofit on a textfield, however the textfield doesn't show anything. Kindly help.

Here is the request from the retrofit service

```
@GET("users/:email")
Call<User> getUser(@Query("email") String email );
```

And how i try to make it display in the text field

```
Call<User> users = api.getUser(email);

    users.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            txtName.setText(response.body().getUserEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

The response from postman looks like this

```
[
{
    "name": "First Name",
    "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "phone": "00000000"
}
]
```

Comment: did you debug and verified if the web call is executing successfully from mobile?

Comment: am a newbie at this, how do i do that please?, though there is a post request that is executing properly from the mobile

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `txtName.setText(response.body().getUserEmail());` and then make sure the response is coming back as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are getting JSON array in response so you need to change your callback accordingly.
change your service call to this

```
Call<List<User>> getUser(@Query("email") String email );
```

then

```
Call<List<User>> users = api.getUser(email);

    users.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
          List<User> users =  response.body();
          if(users!=null && users.size()>0)
           {
             txtName.setText(response.body().get(0).getUserEmail());
           }
          else 
           {
           txtName.setText("No User found");
           }
         }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("USER",t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: i am now getting this error,,,,,,,,,,,, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)

Comment: @ToshGitonga I have updated the answer please use the new code of the onResponse method